# Javascript Eventlistener needs refresh after being used

Tags: javascript, dom, web-frontend

I am learning JavaScript. I tried to implement a simple overlay which transitions on clicking a button and closes after clicking the close button.

But, after closing the overlay, the button that triggers the overlay does not respond on clicking it.
However it works fine after refreshing the page.Why is that so?

Here is the code:

```
 <a href="#" class="fadeInRight wow btn btn-border btn-lg "  onclick="openNav()" data-wow-delay=".6s">Explore More</a>
```

This is the button with function openNav()

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlayed">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
 <div>overlay content</div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/jscript">
    function openNav() {

   var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
   element.classList.toggle("opened");
   }


  function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";


  }
 </script>
```

opened is a class with css content

```
    .opened
   {
     width: 100%;
     height:100%;
     transition: width 6s, height 4s;
     opacity: 1;
   }
```

Thankyou

Comment: The inline style overrides the rules in the stylesheets, hence `width` stays in zero, no matter what the stylesheet rules say.

Comment: @abhilash gopalakrishna on closeNav function why you are setting width 0% ? instead toggle class `.opened `and try

Comment: I have added the opened class to try and apply transformations to the overlay.I tried removing the width-`document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";` and toggling the opened class on closeNav(). I also tried the toggleDisplay() fumction. In both the cases - clicking the close icon fails to toggle the class off. Here, is a link to codepen - [https://codepen.io/itsmeabhilashgk/pen/qKJPVx?editors=1100].  @Aravind S @niklaz @brk @Lars-Olof Kreim  Thank you:)

Comment: @abhilash gopalakrishna `<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>` where is you `closeNav()` function ? define it similar to `toggleDisplay()`...it will fix the isssue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on closeNav function why you are setting width 0% ? instead toggle class .opened

```
element.classList.toggle("opened");
```

this will remove the opened class css.

Answer (score 0):

Well actually you set the width to 0% when closing. This style is an inline style which will stay even if you click open again.

You should instead remove the "opened" class you added while opening.

Answer (score 0):

Your click event is still attached to your button, and it still works, but the functions you call open and to close the overlay, alters the style.

Function that opens overlay, attaches css class to myNav.

Function that closes overlay sets myNav width to 0%.

```
function openNav() {

    var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
    element.classList.toggle("opened");
    element.style.width = "100%"; // or whatever width you need

}


function closeNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
    element.classList.toggle("opened"); //to remove the class, or use .remove explicitly
    element.style.width = "0%";

}
```

But actually, you don't need to change the width of an element, if you add or remove `opened` class, that would be enough.

```
function openNav() {

    var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
    element.classList.toggle("opened");
  //  element.style.width = "100%"; // or whatever width you need

}


function closeNav() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
    element.classList.toggle("opened"); //to remove the class, or use .remove explicitly
   // element.style.width = "0%";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because the `closeNav` function is setting the width to `0`. Infact you do not need two function `openNav` and `closeNav`. You are already using `toggle`. So one function will be enough

```
function toggleDisplay() {
    var element = document.getElementById("myNav");
    element.classList.toggle("opened");
   }
```

Comment: I have added the opened class as I am trying to add transformations to how the overlay content appears. I tried both just toggling the class off at close and also just the function toggleDisplay().

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers showing how to reset the width when you want to re-open the element, as per the question.

It would be better to use: `display: none` and use a hide class. This will take the element you want to hide out of the flow of the page & stop it from interfering with other elements while hidden.

```
.hide { display:none }
```

Then add/remove that class from the element you want to hide/show like so:

```
element.classList.toggle("hide");
```